# Trying to set up reporting an issue to JIRA from test execution

Tags: kiwi-tcms

When I click on the "Report bug" link from a Test Execution, I get the Report Bug dialog, select JIRA as the Issuer Tracker, and click on the Report button. After this, the dialog closes and no issue has been reported to JIRA.

I have followed the [instructions for configuring external bug trackers](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#configure-external-bug-trackers), and have filled out both the Base URL and the API URL with the URL to our JIRA Cloud service. I have filled out the API username, and the Api password. I have tried both my login password and the Atlassian API token I generated for this purpose.

I cannot find any error logs (I don't have root access to the host nor to the docker containers running kiwi_web and kiwi_db, though I'm able to log into them).

Where can I look for what I assume is a log showing the error for this failed action?
Is there something more to configure to get this working? I have read the JIRA section of [the documentation of the tcms.issuetracker.types module](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.issuetracker.types.html#module-tcms.issuetracker.types), including [the section on report_issue_from_testexecution](http://tcms.issuetracker.types), but still haven't found any config to set beyond what I've already set.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: This is what I see in the output from the container when I click on the Report button of the Report Bug dialog:

10.0.4.31 - - [30/Jan/2020:16:39:19 +0000] "POST /json-rpc/ HTTP/1.1" 200 918 "https://qaportal01.irvl.mymbnet.com/runs/19/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"

Edit: Re-starting the containers resolved this problem.

Comment: Sorry for following up so late. Is the originally reported problem with JIRA resolved ?  FTR there's no easy way to debug when connections to external bug trackers fail. This will be alleviated once https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/97 is resolved so you may CC yourself on this issue.

Comment: Yes, this was resolved by re-starting the containers that run Kiwi. I had noticed a few errors at the beginning of the kiwi_web output. They referenced name resolution errors (sorry, that output was not saved). I re-started the containers to see if it would show those errors again. They were no longer present. After that, the Report bug to JIRA feature started working.